# How to traverse two arrays?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I am working with dataTable in javascript with Django, I can collect all the data, I see them by console, but when it comes to display it in its columns I can not, because they are in two different arrays, I do not know if it is possible to add to the first array already created a new key that is called months, with several values, or if on the contrary to access the second array in the months column, I paste the code.

```
function list() {
  var meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero'];
  // vents.items.actividad =  vents.items.actividad.concat(meses);
  // vents.items.actividad.push(...meses)
  // vents.items.actividad.push({"meses": 'Enero, Febrero, Marzo'});
  // var mio = vents.items.actividad;
  console.log(vents.items.actividad);
  // if (select_horario === true){
  //     // alert('estoy dentro');
  // }
  // tblActividades =
  $('#tblActividades').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    destroy: true,
    data: vents.items.actividad,
    columns: [
      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "nombre" },
      { "data": "precio" },
      { "data": "dias" },
      { "data": "horarios" },
      { "data": "meses" },
      { "data": "Opciones" },
    ],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: [-7],
        class: 'text-center',
        orderable: false,
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          return '';
        }
      },
      {
        targets: [-5],
        class: 'text-center',
        orderable: false,
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          return parseFloat(data).toFixed(2) + '€';
        }
      },
      {
        targets: [-1],
        class: 'text-center',
        orderable: false,
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          var buttons = ' ';
          buttons += ' ';
          buttons += '';
          return buttons;
        }
      },
    ],

  }
      });
      // console.clear();
      // console.log(this.items);
      // console.log(this.get_ids());

  }
```

I have tried adding months to the dictionary in different ways, but it always creates another dictionary inside the array. The variable I pass to the data

```
var vents = { items: { alumno: '', date_joined: '', subtotal: 0.00, iva: 0.00, total: 0.00, item: [], actividad: [] },
```

`data: vents.items.actividad`, This data I have tried to put only `vents.items` and then in the columns put `activity.id`, `activity.name`... but it does not work, it does not give error, but nothing comes out, neither with its variants, `actividad[0].nombre` or `actividad0.nombre`, I have looked at different ways on the internet but I can not find it, see if someone can help me please, I'm totally stuck and I do not know how to continue.

```
0: {id: 23, nombre: 'Tenis', horarios: '16:30 - 17:30', dias: Array(5), centros: Array(1), …} 1: {meses: 'Enero, Febrero, Marzo'}
```

On the screen I get two rows, one with all the data, the id, name, timetable, etc... and another row underneath with nothing but the months.

I have tried different solutions as explained in the post, changing the variable types in data, but I can't get the data out of the two arrays.

Comment: I have attached a solution for you. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two separate arrays, to begin with, in each iteration, access the [index] property of the other array:

```js
var n = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22];
var m = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

n.forEach((num1, index) => {
  const num2 = m[index];
  console.log(num1, num2);
});
```